# Create an array of MKPointAnnotation objects

Tags: swift

Currently working with Map Views and adding pins to the map. I know how to add a single point to the map using `addAnotation()` method. Now, I am trying to add multiple points to the MapView in the easiest way. I've fetched the data (latitude, longitude and name from an online XML file) and stored it in an array and now I want to add all those coordinates+name as pins in the map. For doing so I've declared an array of `MKPointAnnotation` objects like so:

```
var pinsArray: [MKPointAnnotation] = []
```

And then for dumping the collected data to I've done the following:

```
    for i in 0...(myFeed.count-1) {

        pinsArray[i].title = myFeed.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("NOMBRE")!.stringValue
        pinsArray[i].coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: myFeed[i].objectForKey("LATITUD")!.doubleValue, longitude: myFeed[i].objectForKey("LONGITUD")!.doubleValue)
        pinsArray[i].subtitle = ""

        mapView.addAnnotation(pinsArray[i])   
    }
```

But when I run the app I get an error saying that the array index is out of range (`fatal error: Array index out of range`). I guess this is a problem on the declaration of the `pinsArray`, I do not really know how to solve this one.

Comment: At which line you are getting this exception?

Comment: First one inside the for loop

Comment: I guess your "pinsArray" is empty.

Comment: I don't really know what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var pinsArray: [MKPointAnnotation] = []

for i in 0...(myFeed.count-1)
{
    let pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation() // First create an annotation.

    pointAnnotation.title = myFeed.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("NOMBRE")!.stringValue
    pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: myFeed[i].objectForKey("LATITUD")!.doubleValue, longitude: myFeed[i].objectForKey("LONGITUD")!.doubleValue)
    pointAnnotation.subtitle = ""

    pinsArray.append(pointAnnotation) // Now append this newly created annotation to array.
}

mapView.addAnnotations(pinsArray) // Add all the annotations to map view at once.
```

Comment: Changed `mapView.addAnnotations(pinsArray)` to `pinsArray.append(pointAnnotation)` and worked perfectly. Thank you!